# Hide / show apps badges in Dock

Tags: macos, notifications, dock, sonoma, focus

When I have a certain focus (e.g. Personal) I’d like to disable all app badges (red dots) in Dock so I’m not bothered by Slack, Mail, etc.

None of the scripts I found here/on GitHub/ on Medium work on Sonoma 14.1
Examples of what I tried and it didn't work:

1. `defaults write com.apple.systempreferences AttentionPrefBundleIDs 0 && killall Dock`
2. [enable_disable_do_not_disturb.sh](https://gist.github.com/vkavun/c9aa9c79a38a60ac1232)
3. [Proper “Do Not Disturb Mode” on Mac](https://kashour.com/proper-do-not-disturb-mode-on-mac/)

I will be happy with advice for a script or app that will sort this enabler of focus runs in macOS Sonoma.

Has anyone got a working setup to hush notification bubbles on macOS as well as iOS manages this function automatically?

Comment: Very good observation. If you could edit this to show any scripts that do what you want even if they fail on the new OS it can help others not on Sonoma as well as might trigger us to improve that script or get you a good answer.

Comment: sure @bmike, done now

Comment: Very good edit. I can drop a bounty on this if it doesn’t get answers in a few days.